# Python requests unicode error

Tags: python, character-encoding, python-requests

I'm using a simple Python script to POST files to a PHP script:

```
...
url = "http://example.com/upload.php"
r = requests.post(url, data=data, files=files)
...
```

I need to catch the response text, which is stored in

```
r.text
```

But when the response contains ASCII characters (e.g. an image file), the Python fails with this error:

```
content = str(self.content, encoding, errors='replace')
TypeError: unicode() argument 2 must be string, not None
```

Is there any way to avoid this error?

Comment: Not handing in `None` as second argument (which *seems* to be `encoding`)? (i.e., it might be useful to have information where `enconding` comes from)

Comment: Post more info, a call stack perhaps?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Binary file such as an image has no associated character encoding. Use `r.content` instead of `r.text`.